# Is there a way to change where the error message is rendered using the standards properties of Ant Design Forms?

Tags: css, reactjs, forms, antd

I'd like to reposition my error messages so they render to the right of the input as to not displace my layout. Is that possible using Antd forms (I'm using and 3.X)? The standard way they render is below the input.
https://3x.ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-validate-static

Answer (score 0):

Can use the rules properties which has `message` property. For example,

```
    <Form.Item
      name="workDescription"
      label="Description:"
      rules={[
        {
          required: true,
          message: "Please Enter Order Description",
          whitespace: true,
        },
      ]}
    >
      <TextArea rows={3} placeholder="Order Description" />
    </Form.Item>
```